# How to pass state props to another component

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass a state variable to another component but i don't get it what i'm doing wrong.

I have a component for radio inputs and I need to pass that taskLabel to Form component.
path is `components/inputs/index.js`

```
const TaskLabel = (props) => {
  const [taskLabel, setTaskLabel] = useState('');

  return (
    <div label={props.taskLabel} >
      <input
        type='radio'
        name='label'
        value='urgent'
        onChange={(e) => setTaskLabel(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type='radio'
        name='label'
        value='not-urgent'
        onChange={(e) => setTaskLabel(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

i want to receive the `taskLabel` value, to use it in submitHandler function.

components/form/index.js

```
const Form = ({taskLabel}) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Text here'
                className='form-input'
                value={task}
                onChange={(e) => {
                   setTask(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <TaskLabel taskLabel={taskLabel} />
        </form>
    )
}
```

This is what i tried, to pass taskLabel props from `label={taskLabel}`.

Comment: As a tip, it's probably not a good idea to name your props the exact same thing as the component, it makes things a bit unreadable

Comment: What is the result? Have you log it out in your `TaskLabel` component?

Comment: @Enfieldli yes, in Form component it's undefined and in input component it's urgent or not-urgent based of what is selected.

Comment: You need to state variable in the top level component. `const [taskLabel, setTaskLabel] = useState('');` this should be implemented in the upper level component of `Form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your state, to `Form` component, like this:
`const [labelProp, setLabelProp] = useState("");`

Your `TaskLabel` component should be
`<TaskLabel label={{ labelProp, setLabelProp }} />`
That means, you send label, as a `prop` to `TaskLabel` component.

In TaskLabel component you need to recive the `prosp`, by passing to component `{label}`.
Next, for every input use `onChange={(e) => label.setLabelProp(e.target.value)}`.

Edited sandbox => [https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-proskuriakova-dhi568?file=/src/components/task-label/index.js](https://In%20%60From%60%20component:%20You%20need%20to%20move%20your%20state,%20to%20%60Form%60%20component,%20like%20this:%20%60const%20%5BlabelProp,%20setLabelProp%5D%20=%20useState(%22%22);%60%20%20Your%20%60TaskLabel%60%20component%20should%20be%20%20%60%3CTaskLabel%20label=%7B%7B%20labelProp,%20setLabelProp%20%7D%7D%20/%3E%60%20That%20means,%20you%20send%20label,%20as%20a%20%60prop%60%20to%20%60TaskLabel%60%20component.%20%20In%20%60TaskLabel%60%20component:%20Here,%20you%20need%20to%20recive%20the%20%60prosp%60,%20by%20passing%20to%20component%20%60%7Blabel%7D%60.%20Next,%20for%20every%20input%20use%20%60onChange=%7B(e)%20=%3E%20label.setLabelProp(e.target.value)%7D%60.%20%20Edited%20sandbox%20=%3E%20%60https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-proskuriakova-dhi568?file=/src/components/task-label/index.js%60)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the concept is "data-down, actions-up". So if you want to pass data down to a lower-level component, you just pass a prop. If you want to update a value from a lower-level component to a higher-level component, you could pass a setter function down as a prop and call that.

Note I just call it `taskLevelProp` for a little more clarity. You should probably use a better name.

**TaskLabel (lower level component)**

```
/* It looks like TaskLabelProp gets passed in from something else.
   Otherwise, you would use useState to get your setter function */
const TaskLabel = ({taskLabelProp, setTaskLabelProp}) => {  
  return (
    <div label={props.taskLabel} >
      <input
        type='radio'
        name='label'
        value='urgent'
        onChange={(e) => setTaskLabelProp(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type='radio'
        name='label'
        value='not-urgent'
        onChange={(e) => setTaskLabelProp(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Form (higher level component)**

```
const Form = () => {
    const [taskLabelProp, setTaskLabelProp] = useState('');
    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Text here'
                className='form-input'
                value={task}
                onChange={(e) => {
                   setTask(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <TaskLabel taskLabel={taskLabelProp, setTaskLabelProp} />
        </form>
    )
}
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

**EDIT:** Made Form use `useState`. Based off your code, I was assuming you were using `useState` at the app level.

Comment: Still don't get it, in my TaskLabel component, i have const [taskLabel, setTaskLabel] = useState(''); . Need to use setTaskLabelProp as a simple function?

Comment: here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-proskuriakova-dhi568?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, don't use `useState` in your taskLabel component. Use it in the higher-level component (i.e. `form` or `app`). If it's going to be used by a parent component, you must useState in the highest level up. To be clear, you should use `useState`, but just not in TaskLabel. I'll update my code to show how you would set it in Form.

Comment: Now, i'm getting an error: `setTaskLabelProp is not a function`. Moved useState in form component.

Comment: If you’re using the codesandbox link above, my guess is that’s because you have it called `setTaskLabelProps` instead of `setTaskLabelProp`

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
const [task, setTask] = useState("");
const [taskLabelProp, setTaskLabelProp] = useState("");
const handleChange = (e) => {
setTaskLabelProp(e.target.value);
};
const submitHandler = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
};
return (
 <div className="App">
  <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Text here"
      className="form-input"
      value={task}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setTask(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
    <TaskLabel
      onChange={handleChange}
      taskLabelProp={taskLabelProp}
      taskLabel="select"
    />
    <button type="submit">fs</button>
  </form>
</div>
);
}
export default App;



const TaskLabel = ({ taskLabel, onChange, taskLabelProp }) => {
 return (
<div label={taskLabel}>
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="label"
    value="urgent"
    onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
    checked={taskLabelProp === "urgent"}
  />
  urgent
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="label"
    value="not-urgent"
    onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
    checked={taskLabelProp === "not-urgent"}
  />
  not-urgent
</div>
);
};
export default TaskLabel;
```